# create tableview using html content in android

Tags: java, android, html, append, stringbuffer

I have to develop one android native application using stringbuffer with html content.

Here i have used below code:

```
PayPalInvoiceItem item1 = new PayPalInvoiceItem();

sb.append("<html><body><table>");

         for (int i = 0; i < Constants.mItem_Detail
                    .size(); i++) {

                String title = Constants.mItem_Detail
                        .get(i).get(
                                SingleMenuItem.KEY_PNAME);

                String qty = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i)
                        .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_QTY);

                String cost = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i)
                        .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_PRICE);

                String total = Constants.mItem_Detail
                        .get(i).get(
                                SingleMenuItem.KEY_TOTAL);
                 total_count=total_count+Integer.parseInt(qty);


            StringBuffer buffer = sb.append("<tr>" + "<td>" + title
                        + "</td><td>" + qty + " * " + cost
                        + "</td>" + " = <td>" + total
                        + "  " + "</td></tr>"); 

             item1.setName(buffer.toString());
```

Now i have to run the application means my output is looking like

```
<html><body><table>"<tr>" "<td>"krishna
                        "</td><td>" 1 " * " 100
                        + "</td>" = <td>" 100
                        + "  " + "</td></tr>
```

But i need the o/p like:

```
krishna  1   100   100
   veni       2   30       60
```

How can i do????
please help me ???

**EDIT:**

here i have to change the below line `item1.setName(buffer.toString());` 
to

```
item.setName(buffer.toString(), "text/html; charset=utf-8"); means am getting following error:
```

The method setName(String) in the type PayPalInvoiceItem is not applicable for the arguments (String,
        String)
How can i resolve these error ????

Answer (score 2):

What is the 'item' you are trying to `setName` on? by the sounds of things you probably just need to create a `WebView` like this:

```
WebView view = new WebView(this);
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
view.loadData(stringBuffer.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
setContentView(view);
```

you also seem to have not terminated the HTML correctly i.e your last write to the `StringBuffer` should be:

```
stringBuffer.append("</table></body></html>");
```

also check your line:

`total_count=total_count+Integer.parseInt(qty);`

should it not be:

```
total_count=total_count+Integer.parseInt(total);
```

Comment: these is native android application.Here i have to send the more than one product detail to paypal.thats y i have used following item.setName.....PayPalInvoiceItem item1 = new PayPalInvoiceItem();
       item1.setName(buffer1.toString());